# When to use "gern" vs. "gerne"

Tags: adverb

What is the difference between "gern" and "gerne"?  When should each be used?

An example I used in a previous question was:

> Ich esse gern Pizza

is that better or worse than:

> Ich esse gerne Pizza

Is there a difference in meaning?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

There is no difference between the two forms in meaning, and they are interchangeable in usage. The dictionary typically even lists them as "gern(e)" rather than as separate entries.


The original form from Old High German down through Middle High German, as [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/gern) and others indicate, was "gerne". The form "gern" is just an example of how often the final "-e" gets dropped from German words in casual usage, and some people may consider it a little more colloquial.


The usage between the two is more of a feeling or the way it sounds in the sentence or circumstance rather than a grammatical requirement. Perhaps you want to say "gerne" to really emphasize something, or perhaps just "gern" with a sense of finality. As you become more familiar with German, you will get a better feel for its rhythm and rhyme and what sounds better to your ears. The choice is yours.

Comment: I've been speaking German for about 3 years now and I felt that I finally understood when to use either one just on account of my Sprachgefühl. Never did I realise that I say "gern" when it's not emphasised, and "gerne" more so when it is. Brilliant. Thanks for enlightening me, it's always helpful to be up to date on these sorts of things.

Comment: _Einen Bedeutungsunterschied zwischen "gern" und "gerne" gibt es nicht, auch in stilistischer Hinsicht ist kein Unterschied festzustellen - beide Formen gelten als gleichwertig._ (Quelle: http://www.spiegel.de/kultur/zwiebelfisch/zwiebelfisch-abc-gerne-gern-a-323744.html)

Answer (score 8):

I would put it into the category of *shortening a word*, especially in *spoken language*, in the same way as you could say

> Ich hab frei

instead of

> Ich habe frei

Comment: I wonder, though, why the abbrevation "habe" usually followed by an apostroph, like in "Ich hab' frei", while for "gerne" you never read "Ich möchte gern' heimfahren".

Comment: @TheBlastOne: In my experience "hab" is *not* followed by an apostrophe in everyday use (which makes sense, since this would defy the purpose of making the word shorter).

Comment: Hab form is not correct because ICH HABE is the formal conjugation from the verb HABEN.

Comment: @user15213: German is my native language, so I do know that _ich habe_ is the correct form. But _ich hab_ is perfectly common in *spoken* language and it is a form which shortens the word in a similar way than the correctly spelled _gerne_.

Comment: Interesting that the entry in Duden for *gern*, *gerne* has the note:  *gern*, auch, ***besonders süddeutsch***: *ger­ne*

Answer (score -1):

Gerne is proper. Gern is dialect.

In the Basel area I have only heard "Gern"... but they drop the final "-e" on most things in Baseldütsh (e.g I have never heard "Schade" only "Schad"). In Schwabenländle (BW) I have heard "Gern" in sentences and "Gerne" only when used alone as a single word answer (e.g. Möchtest du xxx... Gerne...).

Comment: Some of these short forms have made it into standard language, without a particular rule; _gern_ is among them, _schad_ and _müd_ are not, and there are a lot of other examples for each category. So calling _gern_ a dialect form *only* is wrong.

Comment: @chirlu, plz can yo explain me the rules of schad und müd, this is very important for me.